# How to obtain iterator type from template parameter, if template parameter is a reference type

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, containers

The question title may not be super clear, but hopefully the below explains what is my problem.

Let's say I have the following (simplified) class template:

```
template <typename T, typename Container = std::vector<T>>
class MyVector {
  using iterator = typename Container::iterator;
    
  Container data{};

public:
  MyVector(initializer_list<T> l) : data(l) {}
  iterator begin() { return data.begin(); }
};
```

If I create an object like `MyVector<int> vec {1, 2, 3};` it works fine.

However, if I try to create an object like `MyVector<int, std::vector<int>&> vec;` (note the `&`), then in the `iterator` type definition I get the error:

```
Type 'std::vector<int> &' cannot be used prior to '::' because it has no members
```

I tried exploring std::remove_reference and changed the line to:

```
using iterator = typename std::remove_reference<Container>::type::iterator;
```

but this also doesn't work - the error I get in this case is:

```
No type named 'iterator' in 'std::remove_reference<std::vector<int>>'
```

What I would like to achieve is to have a type definition (for iterator) that works if Container is a `std::vector<T>` as well as a reference to `std::vector<T>` (or whatever Container type is used, e.g. std::array - which means I cannot simply use `std::vector<T>::iterator` in the typedef).

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: have you tried `std::decay_t<>`?

Comment: Same issue as with `remove_reference`...

Comment: The error message indicates that you forgot to write the `::type` part of `std::remove_reference<Container>::type::iterator`.

Comment: I tried to replicate your error. The first issue I ran into was the line `Storage(initializer_list<T> l) : data(l) {}` -- is `Storage` supposed to be `MyVector`? That does not inspire confidence that this code snippet is accurate. More importantly, when I made the replacement you claimed to have made, I did not get the error you reported. That line passed -- it's the `Container data{};` line that had an error at that point (because `Container` is a reference).

Comment: Why are you trying to set the `Container` to a reference type in the first place? That makes no sense given the rest of the code shown.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments. Indeed my code was more complex so I've simplified it here and made a couple of typos along the way: I should have run it in advance. However, I still get the same compiler error, but this means the issue lives somewhere else - I'll investigate.

Comment: @JeJo Sorry, I don't get the point of your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `std::remove_reference` will work here. Or you need [`std::remove_reference_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference) version of it

```
using iterator = std::remove_reference_t<Container>::iterator;
//                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That is mean, if you do not have access to the [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14), provide a type alias for this

```
template< class T >
using remove_reference_t = typename remove_reference<T>::type;
```

---

Also note that, in order to work with

```
MyVector<int, std::vector<int>&> vec(v);
//                              ^^^^^^^^ --> not an ini-list
```

class `MyVector` must have a constructor

```
MyVector(Container c) : data(c) {}
```

The `std::initializer_list` will not work with reference qualified container type.

[Here is the demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/fEjxnx4hW)

Comment: The variant in the question is also correct. This is more likely just a mistake/typo in the actual code.

Comment: @JeJo thank you for this. I can also reproduce this code and it works well. I still have the same compiler error in my original code though! But then it means the issue lives somewhere else. I'll investigate...